# Non persistent ActiveRecord model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to add to an existing model some attributes that need not be persisted, or even mapped to a database column.
Is there a solution to specify such thing ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Of course use good old ruby's `attr_accessor`. In your model:

```
attr_accessor :foo, :bar
```

You'll be able to do:

```
object.foo = 'baz'
object.foo #=> 'baz'
```

Comment: How to get this attribute in object's JSON format? Say, I want this attribute to appear in the JSON of the object on the client side. Will I get it? as of now I am not getting it, even though I set this in my create method. How to do it?

Comment: @monteirobrena same thing

Comment: With ActiveModelSerializer I am able to get the attribute in my JSON.

Comment: To get the attribute in your json output, say, using "render :json => object" in your rails controller, please take a look at @RustyToms answer below. Worked for me in Rails 4

Comment: Actually using to_json is not recommended, you should use a json builder or active model serializer

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same problem but I needed to bootstrap the model, so the attribute had to persist after to_json was called.  You need to do one extra thing for this.

As stated by apneadiving, the easiest way to start is to go to your model and add:

```
attr_accessor :foo
```

Then you can assign the attributes you want.  But to make the attribute stick you need to change the attributes method. In your model file add this method:

```
def attributes
  super.merge('foo' => self.foo)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone is wondering how to render this to the view, use the method arguments for the render method, like so:

```
render json: {results: results}, methods: [:my_attribute]
```

Please know that this only works if you set the attr_accessor on your model and set the attribute in the controller action, as the selected answer explained.

Answer (score 4):

From Rails 5.0 onwards you could use `attribute`:

```rb
class StoreListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :non_persisted
  attribute :non_persisted_complex, :integer, default: -1
end
```

With `attribute` the attribute will be created just like the ones being persisted, i.e. you can define the type and other options, use it with the `create` method, etc.

If your DB table contains a matching column **it will be persisted** because `attribute` is also used to affect conversion to/from SQL for existing columns.

see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to use a left join to populate custom attribute. It works if I don't add anything but I also want to be able to set the attribute on a new object and of course it doesn't exist. If I add `attr_accessor` then it always returns `nil` after a `select`. Here's the approach I've ended up with that works for setting on new object and retrieving from left join.

```
after_initialize do
  self.foo = nil unless @attributes.key?("foo")
end

def foo
  @attributes["foo"]
end

def foo=(value)
  @attributes["foo"] = value
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in Rails 4.2. `@attributes` is now an `ActiveRecord::AttributeSet` which supports `[]` but not `[]=`.