# attributes() method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417181/1895325) post, to make attributes stick during `to_json` call, we need to do something like this:

```
def attributes
  super.merge('foo' => self.foo)
end
```

With my beginner's knowledge in Ruby, I fail to understand the following:

- Is there an `attribute` method present for every Ruby class?
- What is `super.merge` doing here? Which hashmap does it append its argument to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi `attributes` is a method provided by [ActiveRecord](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes). If you click on `source` you will notice how it really just exposes the instance variable `@attributes` which is a `hash` (as it can be `nil` it is enforced to a hash through `.to_hash`).

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def attributes
    @attributes.to_hash
  end
end
```

We'll call this method `parent` as we will extend its behaviour in our class. This is possible through [inheritance](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def attributes
    super.merge('foo' => self.foo)
  end
end
```

`attributes` is now calling the parent's method `[Activerecord::Base].attributes` and is adding a new key to the hash.
This code is roughly equivalent and should be easier to read.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def attributes
    attrs = super # eg. { name: "x", created_at: [...], [...] }
    attrs[:foo] = self.foo # eg. { name: "x", foo: [...], ... }
    attrs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not an `#attributes` method for every Ruby class. The class you're using likely inherits from another class or mixes in a module which does (e.g. [`ActiveRecord::Base#attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes)).

That attributes method that you're defining will override any existing `#attributes` method. In the case of an override, Ruby provides a `#super` method, which calls the original method that you're overriding. In this case, you'll be calling the original `#attributes` method which returns a `Hash` of attributes keys and their values (e.g. `{ attr1: 'a', attr2: 'b' }`).

`#merge` is a Hash function that you're calling on the Hash that the original `#attributes` call returns (e.g `{ attr1: 'a', attr2: 'b' }`). `#merge` creates a new hash consisting of the original attributes hash combined with the key-value pairs provided in the second hash.

From the Ruby 2.2 docs on `Hash#merge`:

> #### merge(other_hash) → new_hash click to toggle source
>
> #### merge(other_hash){|key, oldval, newval| block} → new_hash
>
> Returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the
>   contents of hsh. If no block is specified, the value for entries with
>   duplicate keys will be that of other_hash. Otherwise the value for
>   each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key,
>   its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.
>
> ```
> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
> h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
> h1.merge(h2)   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
> h1.merge(h2){|key, oldval, newval| newval - oldval}
>                #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>54,  "c"=>300}
> h1             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> ```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Some notes about your example: `'foo' => self.foo`

- You don't need to specify `self` in `self.foo`. `foo` alone should suffice. That's really only needed for assignments `self.foo = 'whatever'` and in cases where you've defined another `foo` in the same scope.
- Make sure that they type of the key you're providing matches the type of the keys that `#attributes` is returning.

Case 1: `#attributes` returns a Hash of Strings -> Values, so merge in a hash with String keys (ActiveRecord does this.)

```
{ 'attr1' => 1, 'attr2' => 'b' }.merge( { 'attr3' => '3' }
```

Case 2: `#attributes` returns a Hash of Symbols -> Values, so merge in a hash with Symbol keys:

```
{ :attr1 => 1, :attr2 => 'b' }.merge( { :attr3 => '3' }
```

Comment: Can you please locate `attributes` method in `ActiveRecord`'s [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/4.2.1)?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are a synonym properties, variables etc on your class. Not all classes contain attributes but data models generally exist to encapsulate the attributes and methods they contain, as well as some behavior to modify and/or operate on them. To respond with a json representation of a model you would generally do something like this in your controller.

```
respond_to :json
def tags
  render :json => User.find(params[:id]).tags
end
```