# Create a variable in after_find of model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need generate a variable for send a the view, for example i have this:

```
def after_find
    unless self.photo.nil?
        if File.exist?(Rails.root + 'public/uploads/tournaments/' +  self.photo)
            self.photo = '/uploads/tournaments/' + self.photo
        else
            self.photo = "http://placehold.it/250x400"
        end
    else    
        self.photo = "http://placehold.it/250x400"
    end
end
```

It runs well that variable is an attribute of db migration,the problem is when I declare something that is not an attribute of db migration

```
self.variable1 = "hello world"
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non persistent ActiveRecord model attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986792/non-persistent-activerecord-model-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have an attribute on a model but this attribute is not part of your database you can define it as accessor. In your model just add

```
#app/models/tournament.rb
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :variable1
end
```

EDIT:

However in this particular case you should consider the performance penalty from checking the filesystem every time you load a `Tournament` object.

Using gem like Carrierwave or Paperclip is a much better solution!

Comment: Thanks  for  your answer , i will add this gem :D

Comment: From those two I would recommend Paperclip move