# Add Non Persistent attribute In Active Record JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Is is possible to create a custom model attribute and get its value included by default, whenever that model is called?

I have a model named `Video`. It has an attribute named `name`. It contains the name of the video `sample-video.mp4`. I want to create  two custom attributes named `iphone_url` and `android_url` for model.

Both attributes will have different urls concatenated with name. So, `iphone_url` will have `http://link1/+name+/playlist.m3u8` where as `android_url` will have `http://link2/+name`

Is it possible that whenevr i call that model, both attributes are automatically added(in JSON response)?

I tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986792/non-persistent-activerecord-model-attributes).

I was able to add custom attributes by using `attr_accessor`, but their value is always null.  May be because their value needs to be set manually first.

So how to do this?

**Edit**:  Currently, i'm doing like this:

```
videos = Array.new

# Dirty, but works      
Video.all.each do |video|
    video = video.attributes

    wowza_server = "X.X.X.X:XXXX/AppName/"
    custom_attributes = {:wowza_urls => {:ios => "http://"+wowza_server+"mp4:"+video[:name])+"/playlist.m3u8", :android => "rtsp://"+wowza_server+video[:name])}}

    videos << video.merge(custom_attributes)
end

render :json => videos, status: :ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really what [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) was made for.

> Jbuilder gives you a simple DSL for declaring JSON structures that beats massaging giant hash structures.

You're starting to massage a giant hash structure.

I'm assuming this is an index view, in which case it look something like this:

```
json.array! @videos do |video|
  json.my_field video.my_field
  json.iphone_url video.iphone_url
  json.android_url video.android_url
end
```

On your `app/model/video.rb`

```
class Video
  def iphone_url
    "some_url_to_build"
  end
  ...
end
```